# Ubuntu 22.04 cannot find where software is installed?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, uninstall

I installed metadata-cleaner sometime ago and have since then tried removing it from both the gnome-software and the snap-store. However it is still there when I search using the start key ('windows' key). It is not just an icon, the app actually opens. I'm not sure what is going on and where this software is installed.
How do I find it and remove it?

**EDIT**

The output of `apt policy metadata-cleaner && snap list | grep metadata-cleaner`

```
metadata-cleaner:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.8-1
  Version table:
     1.0.8-1 500
        500 http://gpl.savoirfairelinux.net/pub/mirrors/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: How you installed the app will determine the best way of removing it. Did you install it using `gnome-software` or the *snap store*?  or some other way?  What type of package is it?  I find *deb* package of that name, but do see a `metadata-cleaner  2.5.4    soumyadghosh  -      View and clean metadata in files` so `snap remove metadata-cleaner` should remove it.

Comment: I actually don't remember how I installed it, which is why I was checking both stores. I did what you suggest. Both snap and apt say that this package is not installed!

Comment: `whereis metadata-cleaner` will provide some useful clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meetadata Cleaner app is listed at [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/search?q=metadata-cleaner), so it's possible that it could have been installed that way. `flatpak list` lists all installed flatpak  applications and/or runtimes.

If metadata-cleaner is a .deb package then Synaptic package manager (`sudo apt install synaptic`) should be able to completely remove it.

Comment: thanks, it was a flatpak!